# vuejs: filters in external file?

Tags: vue.js

`src/app.js` looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueResource);

const app = require("./app.vue");
const f = require('./filters');

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {name: 'home', path: '/', component: home}
    ]
});

new Vue({
    router: router,
    filters: f,
    render: h => h(app)
}).$mount("#app");
```

`src/filters/index.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    season: (value) => {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

Using `webpack` to roll it up, but the filter doesn't work and Vue warns me like so:

```
build.js:830 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: season
(found in <Anonymous>)
```

How can I properly put my filters in a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not registering that filter globally, you are only registering it to be used in the template of `#app`. But your app immediately renders the component, `app`.

To make the `season` filter available globally, use

```
Vue.filter("season", f.season)
```

in your app.js.

Or you can import the filters into the components that use them.

Comment: can I do something like `Vue.filter(f)` so it imports all the filters defined in that file, versus adding a `Vue.filter()` call for each filter?

Comment: I guess I could do a `let filter of f` and call `Vue.filter` for each but that seems inefficient too...

Comment: No. You would have to go with your second option and loop through them. Or import Vue into your filters.js and just add them there as you define them.

Comment: Personally, I would rather you import the filters you use into a component specifically because, as someone not familiar with your code, I don't have to go hunting all over creation to know what you are doing.

Comment: i get that, but I'm coming from Flask/jinja2/python and it's great to have these global filters, as long as you keep them defined in a central location (`/filters/index.js` for me), it's pretty easy to go right to the source...

Comment: @Wells In any case, you now have several options for making them global.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop all filters from an array created inside your file for example.

```
const filters =
[
   {
     name: 'season',
     execute: (value) => { return 'foo'; }
   }
]

export default filters
```

And in you main.js you do the loop,

```
import filters from './filters'

filters.forEach(f => {
   Vue.filter(f.name, f.execute)
})
```

[]s

Answer (score 0):

Its in vuejs 1.0. Two-way filter has been removed from vuejs 2.0.

see [git issue discuss](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2756)
and [solution](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Two-Way-Filters-replaced)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!